# ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable The executable contains bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, maui

I have a .NET MAUI application that is built and signed in release mode using XCode 14.2 on a Mac that targets .NET SDK `7.0.203`. When I create the package locally (or via GitHub Action) and attempt to distribute via TestFlight, I get the following email from Apple:

```
ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable '***.app/Frameworks/ZipArchive.framework/ZipArchive' contains bitcode.
```

Which puzzled me a bit as we dont have any dependency on that framework nor we are using any native library in the app. Upon a quick google (and poking in the app contents) the package that apple is referring to is [this](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) one. Which is a archive utility. It seems apple is using it to compress and decompress the package on device if I am to guess. I could find any references on how to disable the bitcode when building MAUI app for the iOS. Has anyone faced the same issue? Any pointer how you have been able to resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the solution is the add some build task via this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12863)