# App store submission failed because of bitcode contained

Tags: ios, .net, maui

Same issue here - just uploaded the first version of a .NET MAUI app and it failed due to containing bitcode

```
ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/FirebaseInstallations.framework/FirebaseInstallations' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/FirebaseMessaging.framework/FirebaseMessaging' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/GoogleAPIClientForREST.framework/GoogleAPIClientForREST' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/GoogleDataTransport.framework/GoogleDataTransport' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/leveldb.framework/leveldb' contains bitcode.

ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'TimeClockNow.Mobile.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework/nanopb'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable The executable contains bitcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76004631/itms-90482-invalid-executable-the-executable-contains-bitcode)

Comment: @Jason I've checked this link already but have not found any proper solution. this .csproj relalted code will not work any other solution you have ?? How to disable bit code like

Comment: @user16258378 Please try to use these MSBuild tasks to get rid of that pesky bitcode, see https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10989#issuecomment-1304317816.