Asset Validation Failed in App Store Connect

Asset validation failedInvalid Executable. The executable 'ASE.app/Frameworks/MapplsAPICore.framework/MapplsAPICore' contains bitcode. (ID: 1a3605b-9d82-48ce-9200-fc8f3da1a395
Asset validation failedInvalid Executable. The executable ' ASE.app/Frameworks/MapplsAPIKit.framework/MapplsAPIKit' contains bitcode. (ID: c18d80b-227d-45ad-808d-5909433f66d3)
Asset validation failedInvalid Executable. The executable ' ASE.app/Frameworks/MapplsLMS.framework/MapplsLMS' contains bitcode. (ID: 3fd6caf-707e-4d24-a823-c36957de8c8f)
Asset validation failedInvalid Executable. The executable ' ASE.app/Frameworks/MapplsMap.framework/MapplsMap' contains bitcode. (ID: ef56be3-04ec-442a-8b12-1ff72f9a1bdc)
Asset validation failedInvalid Executable. The executable ' ASE.app/Frameworks/MapplsNearbyFinder.framework/MapplsNearbyFinder' contains bitcode. (ID: 4c5a227b-760e-45d1-9f3a-757a4f52f72)
Upload Symbols FailedThe archive did not include a dSYM for the CometChatSDK.framework with the UUIDs [22A5DB26-6B5-3389-B93D-C3D7606C10C9]. Ensure that the archives dSYM folder includes a DWARF file for CometChatSDK.framework with the expected UUIDs.
Upload Symbols FailedThe archive did not include a dSYM for the CometChatStarscream.framework with the UUIDs [1981EDE-3926-3F59-82D1-A30ADE2B83F9]. Ensure that the archives dSYM folder includes a DWARF file for CometChatStarscream.framework with the expected UUIDs."

I am trying to upload my iOS application to the App Store. While uploading the application I am getting multiple errors.
I have updated the pod 'MapplsMap' #, '5.13.14'   pod 'MapplsNearbyFinder' #, '2.0.2' but still this error is happening.

This question is similar to: asset validation failed invalid executable. the executable 'myapp.app/frameworks/cardio.framework/cardio' contains bitcode. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527343/app-store-team-error-saying-your-app-contains-bitcode-after-application-submis, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77329802/app-store-submission-failed-because-of-bitcode-contained, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78993520/invalid-executable-the-executable-appname-app-frameworks-hermes-framework-herm.
